# Windows drive letters for non-Latin languages

Tags: windows, drive-letter

Windows uses characters A-Z for drive letters on English installations.

For languages with non-Latin character sets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic etc), are letters A-Z still assigned to drives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short... yes.  Farther still... non-latin letters that appear to be the same letter in English do not translate the same.  For instance, the Russian `с` (cyrillic s) will not translate to the latin `c`.  For a test... copy `с:\` into an address bar in the windows explorer  and it will complain that it does not exist... where as `c:\` will show the contents of your `c` drive.